# Почему глобальная переменная не изменяется после её изменения в функции

Tags: python, namespace

Для понимания пространства имен и тестов создал скрипт из 3х файлов:

**run.py**

```
print(1)
from app import module1
print(6)    
if __name__ == '__main__':
   print(7)
   module1.prepare_task()
```

**app__init__.py  (empty)**

**app\module1.py**

```
print(2)
print(5)
task_params = {1:11}
print(id(task_params))
from app import module2
def prepare_task():
    print(8)
    global task_params
    print(dir(), id(task_params))
    task_params = {}
    print(dir(), id(task_params))
    task_params['task1'] = {'task': module2.task1, 'data': 'some data'}
    print(task_params)
    task_params['task1']['task']()
```

**app\module2.py**

```
print(3)
from app.module1 import task_params
print(4)
print(task_params)
def task1():
    print(9)
    print(dir(), id(task_params))
    print(task_params)
```

Вопрос вот в чём:

1) если запустить как есть, вывод последней строки будет следующим и он меня устраивает:

```
{1: 11, 'task1': {'task': <function task1 at 0x0000022962905598>, 'data': 'some data'}}
```

Т.е.  получаю измененный в функции модуля 1 словарь.

2) если же раскомментировать в app\module1.py следующие 2 строки:
global task_params
task_params = {}

то вывод последней строки будет следующим и он меня НЕ устраивает:
{1: 11}
**Я ожидал увидеть следующую последнюю строку:**

```
{'task1': {'task': <function task1 at 0x0000022962905598>, 'data': 'some data'}}
```

Выходит, что функция prepare_task() меняет глобальную переменную локально.
Я не могу понять, почему так происходит?
Вероятно я что-то упустил?

Помогите разобраться в таком поведении скрипта, пожалуйста.

Comment: `2) если же раскомментировать в app\module1.py следующие 2 строки: global task_params task_params = {}` а ожидалось что будет `{'task1': {'task': <function task1 at 0x0000022962905598>, 'data': 'some data'}}`?

Comment: >а ожидалось что будет...
Да, верно.
Поправил вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"... операции непосредственного изменения объектов не рассматривают имена как локальные – это свойственно только операциям присваивания. Например, если имени L присвоен список, определенный на верхнем уровне в модуле, то такая инструкция, как L.append(X), внутри функции не будет классифицировать имя L как локальное, тогда как инструкция L = X — будет. В первом случае происходит изменение объекта списка, на который указывает L, а не самого имени L, – список L будет найден в глобальной области видимости, как обычно, и Python изменит этот список, без необходимости объявления имени global (или nonlocal). Этот пример должен помочь явственнее ощутить различия между именами и объектами: операция, изменяющая объект, совсем не то, что операция присваивания объекта имени." [Доступ на присваивание к нелокальным именам](https://foxford.ru/wiki/informatika/oblasti-vidimosti-peremennyh-v-python)

В нашем случае, когда в первом модуле мы пишем task_params = {}, мы делаем переменную task_params локальной. Вот и весь фокус.

Comment: Фантастика! Вы ответили именно тем, что я так искал!! Спасибо Вам огромное!